# Creating a folder and loops

Tags: windows, directory

The question is related to speed over safety.
When my program will check if a folder exists in a loop everytime, it will decrease the speed. So:

Is it needed to do a check if a folder exist before creating it so it will not be created over and over, or Windows will not let to recreate the same folder repetitive and replace it?

Is it safe to leave it without checking the existence of the folder?

I meant not about programming language used, but more about software behavior in the case, if we have spam of generating folder with same name over and over, so more hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it needed to do a check if a folder exist before creating it so it will not be created over and over, or Windows will not let to recreate the same folder repetitive and replace it?

I can't think of a single file system abstraction for creating directories that erase an existing one if it already exists.

You didn't say which API you are invoking, but [CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya) will return 0 and GetLastError will return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if the directory exists.  So just treat that error case as success.

Regarding your hypothetical and desire to optimize around it. Always build for reliability and robustness first. Fix the hypothetical performance issues after they are proven not to be just hypothetical. (i.e. measure perf first, then fix perf issue).